# My Angular2 app in Heroku doesn't read configuration variables

Tags: angular, heroku

I’m making a web page in Angular2 and I want to use configuration variables of Heroku since I don’t want to expose some info (API URL) in my script.
I know I can set my config vars in setting page of my Heroku app and I already set 2 vars.
I didn’t install heroku-cli.

However I could not read config var in my Angular2 app which was deployed to Heroku. One of my config var `(key, value)` is `('G_CONST', 'abc123')`. It is for testing. I use `console.log(process.env.G_CONST);` in my app-service.ts. The result was: undefined. I wonder if there are steps I did not notice. If any, please tell. 
If it’s impossible to hide information in my Heroku Angular2 app, then I’ll choose to expose my API URL. After all, it is the most important part in my app.

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJS you have to make REST API call to get the `config vars`

```
GET /apps/{app_id_or_name}/config-vars
```

using `env` variable you can access `config vars` in server side code only.

For details example please refer - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#config-vars